# $ |x_{n} - y_{n}| < \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow |x'_{n} - y'_{n}| < \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This came from a proof on uniform continuity theorem. My textbook claims that if sequence $(x_j)$ and $(y_j)$ on a compact set D have the condition that $ |x_n - y_n| < \frac{1}{n}$, and $(x'_j)$, $(y'_j)$ are any convergent subsequence
of $(x_j)$ and $(y_j)$ respectively, then $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such  that $\forall n > m, |x'_n - y'_n| < \frac{1}{n} $. Intuitively, I think it is true. If $x'_n$ and $y'_n$ had the same index in their original sequence, this is immediately true. But I do not know how to justify the case where both subsequences have no common index (for example: first subsequence made of only even indices and second sequence made of only odd indices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am misreading, this is false as stated.

Counterexample:  suppose  $x_{2n}=0=y_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}=1=y_{2n+1}$.  Then the first inequality is trivially satisfied.

Now choose $x'_i=x_{2i}=0$ and $y'_i=y_{2i+1}=1$.  Then both converge (obviously) but the second inequality is false.

Comment: So the proof is invalid. I found a better proof involving open covers so it is fine.